# Reconstruct a protein's 3D structure from a pair-wise distance matrix

Tags: pdb, protein-structure, 3d-structure

What is a good method to reconstruct a protein's 3D structure from a pair-wise distance matrix of residues?

I think the question is self-explanatory. I know of this [method](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/31/21/3499/194596) 
but it seems that it uses contact maps, which actually use a certain cut-off. I don't have a cutoff based contact matrix but a matrix with actual distances.

Comment: You have distance between alpha carbons or beta carbons (or other atoms of the residues)? Usually a threshold is set because below certain measure it can't be and above certain threshold it doesn't mean a contact between the residues. Do you have any other information besides the distance matrix, like the sequence of the protein?

Comment: @llrs They are only carbon alpha distances and I want to reconstruct the backbone with carbon alphas and no more atoms.No more information, just the distances between carbon alphas for each residue.

Comment: You could use the multidimensional scaling approach, but I suspect it might propose invalid angles between the backbone. It would be possible to use it as a starting point before checking the angles between the backbone. But I don't know if there is any software to do this (it is a strange problem to have), or either you know the sequence or the sequence and the structure, but just the distance is strange.

Answer (score -1):

Finding coordinates of N points that preserve (as well as possible) pair-wise distances from an NxN matrix is called [multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling).

But I don't enough about the context of your problem to tell if/how it is applicable.